# JavaScript one click button

Tags: javascript, html

Please I want to create a button that can be clicked only once in 24hrs in js but I don't really know how to put it up.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Disable Button</title>
<script>
function doSomething () {
document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = false;}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="doSomething()"
value="Click Here To Do Something"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Clicked only once by a each visitor? Clicked only once by a single visitor and all the others will have to wait? What's the idea here? Keep in mind that Javascript is a client side language. No matter how "secure" you try to make it, anyone with a bit of understanding on how browsers work can easily reset the timer whenever they want to.

Comment: I mean for each visitors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.onload = () => {
   //on load of the page it will check for same day and disable/enable.
   let lastclicked = localStorage.getItem('lastclicked') || '';
   document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = lastclicked === new Date().toDateString();
}

function doSomething () {
   localStorage.setItem('lastclicked', new Date().toDateString());
   document.getElementById("myButton").disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: this actually work for all visitors, i need each visitors

Comment: Browser is for each visitor only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you need to save to date and time of the last trigger somewhere in local storage or cookies so next when the button is triggered it checked the date in storage if that exists then it will check the date.
hope so it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var todayclick = true;
var buttonval = document.getElementById("myButton");

buttonval.click(function() {
 if (todayclick ) {
        alert("Error!");
 }
 else {
      variable += 1;
      todayclick = false;
 }
 setTimeout(function() {
        todayclick = true;
  }, 86400);
});
```